# Why CSharpCompilation.GetDiagnostics method in Blazor wasm application throw System.PlatformNotSupportedException when used in the async method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, roslyn, blazor-webassembly

I want to compile C# code in the Blazor wasm application using Roslyn CSharpCompilation. When I **invoke the async RunCompilation method** (using the button) **as the first method in the application,** the **CSharpCompilation GetDiagnostics throws an exception** System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.

If I **invoke method RunSync first** and **then async method RunCompilation as the second in the application**, **it works as expected**. It writes: "(1,5): warning CS0219: The variable 'x' is assigned, but its value is never used" on the console.

Here is the complete repository:
https://github.com/ekral/CSharpCompilationBlazorTest

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
@using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp

<button @onclick="RunSync">Run sync</button>
<button @onclick="RunCompilation">Run compilation</button>

@code
{
    [Inject]
    public HttpClient Client { get; set; }

    public async Task RunCompilation()
    {
        var stream = await Client.GetStreamAsync("_framework/System.Private.CoreLib.dll");
        MetadataReference reference = MetadataReference.CreateFromStream(stream);

        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Test")
            .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication))
            .AddReferences(new MetadataReference[] { reference })
            .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("int x = 0;", new CSharpParseOptions(LanguageVersion.Latest)));

        // Should write:
        // (1,5): warning CS0219: The variable 'x' is assigned but its value is never used
        foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in compilation.GetDiagnostics())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void RunSync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("void RunSync");
    }
}
```

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
    <BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport>false</BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="3.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

### Update

I think that it may be connected to this issue because Roslyn does use Parallel.For inside GetDiagnostics:
[Blazor client developers can use Parallel.For in their applications](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43411#issuecomment-791237032)

And temporal solution until the WebAssembly Threads are ready is to set concurrentBuild option on CSharpCompilationOptions false.

```cs
CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Test")
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication, concurrentBuild: false))
    .AddReferences(new MetadataReference[] { reference })
    .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("int x = 0;", new CSharpParseOptions(LanguageVersion.Latest)));
```

Comment: `When I invoke the async RunCompilation method (using the button) as the first method in the application, the CSharpCompilation GetDiagnostics throws an exception System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.` When I invoke RunCompilation first,I will not get the error.

Comment: Thank you, @YiyiYou. Could you please share the complete solution? To make sure, did you invoke the RunCompilation method using the "Run compilation" button, and the runtime was Blazor wasm and not Blazor server?  I have tried it on three different setups with both .NET 5 and .NET 6 preview, and I always got that exception.